# SQL convert 5 digit integer to date not based on 1/1/1900

Tags: sql, date, casting, type-conversion, date-conversion

I have output of a sql query that yields an onboard date that should be 4/15/2017 as integer 79001. I have attempted changing the cell format once exported into MS Excel & the Try_Convert function in SQL.

Comment: Please show us your code so we can help you figure out where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That would be about a century earlier.  Simple date arithmetic suggests that the start date is '1800-12-28'.  This would suggest subtracting 36,162 from the Excel cell and then converting to a date format.